# pairwise combinations to matrix/table representation

Tags: python, matrix, combinations, python-itertools

I think this is probably something people have already solved, and may even be some baked in functionality I'm missing, so I figured I'd ask before I reinvent the wheel.

Basically, given some pairwise output from `itertools.combinations`, I'd like to represent it as a matrix/table of each comparison.

So far, I'm roughly up to this point:

```
from itertools import combinations

def chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
    
x = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)]

[print(i) for i in chunks([i[1]+j[1] for i, j in combinations(x, 2)], len(x)-1)]
```

This gives me a matrix-style output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7, 7]
[8, 9]
[None, None, None]
```

I'm not sure where the `None`s are coming from just yet as the output of `chunks([i[1]+j[1] for i, j in combinations(x, 2)], len(x)-1)` is:

```
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 7], [8, 9]]
```

But I can look into that later on (but feel free to point out my obvious mistake!)

I'd ideally like to end up with a pairwise matrix (ideally with the names of the comparisons attached too so it would appear something like:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
A        3    4    5    6
B             5    6    7
C                  7    8
D                       9
E
```

It clear my naive approach of `chunk`ing by the length of the input data isn't quite right either as the `7` belonging to the `C`+`D` comparison is on the wrong line. I'd forgotten to account for the additional entry disappearing each time.

If there's a better way altogether, I'm happy to change the approach. I've focussed on using `itertools` for this as it may end up being run over large files with potentially thousands of comparisons in a bigger script with other calculations etc happening, so avoiding self, and repeat comparisons is ideal.

#### Edit:

To add, I'd like to subsequently be able to output the matrix that I depicted, with the row and column names, to a tsv/csv or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a matrix as you describe, using 0's for the "blanks":

```
[[(a[1]+b[1] if a[0]<b[0] else 0) for b in x] for a in x]
```

To print it out:

```
print("\t".join(['']+[a[0] for a in x]))
for a in x:
    print("\t".join([a[0]] + [(str(a[1]+b[1]) if a[0]<b[0] else '') for b in x]))
```

Comment: Sorry I think I wasn't clear about the output. Getting it into matrix form is great, but I'd like to then be able to put this matrix out in to a tsv or csv etc., with the column/row headings. I'll edit my question.